# Merge List of identical objects into single one with bool properties C#

Tags: c#

I'm really trying to figure it out how to do it and if its possible, but seems I'm stuck.

I have some object

```
public class Obj 
{
    public bool Allow { get; set;}
    public bool Forbidden { get; set; }
    public bool Forgotten { get; set; }
}
```

And I have `List<Obj>`, which all of those objects in the list has to be combined in single `Obj`, where if the property is `true` in any of those objects should be set to `true`, else keep it `false`.

E.g.

```
List<Obj> list = new List<Obj>() 
{
    new Obj() { Allow = false, Forbidden = false, Forgotten = true },
    new Obj() { Allow = true, Forbidden = false, Forgotten = false },
    new Obj() { Allow = false, Forbidden = false, Forgotten = true }
}
```

In that case I would get new `Obj` with values `Allow = true (in one of the objects its set to True), Forbidden = false, Forgotten = true (there is object with this property set to True as well)`

Is this possible in elegant way without doing multiple `.Where()` for example?

Answer (score 2):

This should work:

```
public Obj CoalesceObjs(IEnumerable<Obj> items)
{
    var result = new Obj();
    foreach(var item in items)
    {
        result.Allow = result.Allow || item.Allow;
        result.Forbidden = result.Forbidden || item.Forbidden;
        result.Forgotten = result.Forgotten || item.Forgotten;

        if (result.Allow && result.Forbidden && result.Fogotten) return result;
    }
    return result;
}
```

If you *really* want to use linq, you could also do this:

```
var seed = new Obj(); 
list.Aggregate(seed, (cur, next) => {
    cur.Allow = cur.Allow || next.Allow;
    cur.Forbidden = cur.Forbidden || next.Forbidden;
    cur.Fogotten = cur.Forgotten || next.Forgotten;
    return cur;
});
//seed is now also the result
```

Which I could again wrap in a function like so:

```
public Obj CoalesceObjs(IEnumerable<Obj> items)
{
    var seed = new Obj(); 
    return list.Aggregate(seed, (cur, next) => {
        cur.Allow = cur.Allow || next.Allow;
        cur.Forbidden = cur.Forbidden || next.Forbidden;
        cur.Fogotten = cur.Forgotten || next.Forgotten;
        return cur;
    });
}
```

**Update: added an early-exit to the first option.**

Answer (score 1):

If performance doesn't matter, a really elegant and really easy to read way is like:

```
Obj result = new Obj()
{
    Allow = list.Any(o => o.Allow),
    Forbidden = list.Any(o => o.Forbidden),
    Forgotten = list.Any(o => o.Forgotten)
};
```

Note that you are querying your list 3 times, for a potentially more performant solution you could make use of LINQs `Aggregate`. But it really depends where the first `true`s are occuring.

Comment: It might be much better than `Aggregate`, since `Any` exits early if it finds a `true` and `Aggregate` always goes to the end.

Answer (score 0):

I've actually made it with reflection, because I don't want to go and add related properties if new one comes

```
public static T MergeInSingleObjectBool<T>(this List<T> list)
        where T : new()
    {
        var obj = new T();

        foreach (var item in list)
        {
            var type = item.GetType();
            foreach (var prop in type.GetProperties())
            {
                var name = prop.Name;
                var value = (bool)type.GetProperty(name).GetValue(item);
                if (value)
                {
                    obj.GetType().GetProperty(name).SetValue(obj, value);

                    // we found true for our prop
                    break;
                }
            }
        }

        return obj;
    }
```

Comment: you should have a `break;` in the `if` block, since you don't need to continue when you find a `true` result.

Comment: Also think about adding a ```break``` at your first level loop, if all properties are already ```true```.